# File name is not showing at the top of the window in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, control-panel

This is the Control Panel Window when it is active:
[image: Active Control Panel]

And same window, but inactive:
[image]

As you can see, it seems like the name is there, but the font is white. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you unintentionally changed the font color of Windows 10. It could also happen that one or another recently installed programs changed this setting.

You can easily change it back in the *Ease of access* settings. Try to choose the *None* from the *Choose a theme* options. 
If this didn't help you can try to go to *Closed captions* and play with a text colors settings there.

Hope this helps.

[image: Ease of access settings window]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out. Windows 10 has weird color options in different places:

1. **Control Panel** - You can go to `Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Personalization` and change the Theme. These are very broad changes, and you have very little control over colors, and you pretty much have to pick something with a stupid background to make any real changes
2. **Settings** - Go to `Start > Settings > Personalization` This gives you a lot more individual control, although it's still pretty crappy because of restrictions - you have to pick from pre-made colors, or let it choose colors based on your background.